# Displaying a scheduled job under a scheduled time

Tags: python, child-process, scheduled-tasks

I use `at` to schedule jobs and `atq` to display the scheduled jobs. But it mildly irritates me in that I have to look up each job individually.  I wrote a Python script to display the scheduled job under the scheduled time.

(In my world all the commands will begin 'task')

So instead of

> ```
> stafflinux$atq
> 8   Mon Aug 18 09:00:00 2014 a joseph
> 10  Tue Aug 19 09:00:00 2014 a joseph
> 15  Thu Aug 21 09:00:00 2014 a joseph
> 12  Fri Aug 22 09:00:00 2014 a joseph
> 9   Thu Aug 21 09:00:00 2014 a joseph
> 14  Sat Aug 30 09:00:00 2014 a joseph
> 7   Sun Aug 17 09:00:00 2014 a joseph
> 6   Mon Aug 18 09:00:00 2014 a joseph
> 11  Sat Aug 30 09:00:00 2014 a joseph
> stafflinux$
> ```

My script produces

> ```
> stafflinux$./atscript.py 
> 8  Mon Aug 18 09:00:00 2014 a joseph
> task "buy a four-way plug adapter" 
> task "see guy about meeting" 
> -----------------------------------------
> 10  Tue Aug 19 09:00:00 2014 a joseph
> task "bring back personal effects from office" 
> -----------------------------------------
> 15  Thu Aug 21 09:00:00 2014 a joseph
> task "book tickets for next week"
> -----------------------------------------
> ```

I'm looking for any feedback - particularly in terms of 'pythonic' style and any and all tricks I may have missed:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
os.system("atq > attemp.txt") 
file = open("attemp.txt")
line = file.readline()
while line: 
    number =line[:2]
    print line.strip()
    os.system("at -c "+ number+ "| grep task")
    line=file.readline()
    print '-----------------------------------------'
print line
os.system("rm attemp.txt")
```

Answer (score 3):

Your script creates a temporary file unnecessarily, uses `os.system` which is not recommended, and other messy things. Consider this alternative:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import re

re_job_number = re.compile(r'\d+')

for atq_line in subprocess.Popen(['atq'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout:
    job_number = re_job_number.search(atq_line).group()
    print atq_line.strip()
    for at_line in subprocess.Popen(['at', '-c', job_number], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout:
        if at_line.startswith('task '):
            print at_line.strip()
    print '-' * 40
```

Advantages:

- No need for a temporary file to save the `atq` output, you can process it directly
- For running shell commands, `subprocess` is the recommended way, `os.system` is discouraged
- No need for a `grep` process, you can handle the output filtering of `at -c` in Python itself

Also, writing the first line this way makes the script more portable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If you write as `#!/usr/bin/python` then you are effectively hard-coding the Python path, and it might not be the same in all systems.

Finally, I recommend writing `print(something)` instead of `print something`, to keep your script ready for migrating to Python 3 someday.

Comment: Hard-coding `#!/usr/bin/python` is not necessarily a bad idea — it's a judgement call.

Answer (score 2):

You should segment your code in a way that makes it more readable.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

os.system("atq > attemp.txt") 
file = open("attemp.txt")
line = file.readline()

while line: 
    number =line[:2]
    print line.strip()
    os.system("at -c "+ number+ "| grep task")
    line=file.readline()
    print '-----------------------------------------'

print line
os.system("rm attemp.txt")
```

Additionally, you should use the `with` context manager, which takes care of file closing and error handling for you. Also, you should avoid using strings all over the place and store the filename in a variable. You should also avoid setting unnecessary variables (like `number`). Additionally, use Python's string multiplication abilities ('-' * 40 will print 40 '-'). Your script would now look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

filename = 'attemp.txt'
os.system("atq > " + filename)

with open(filename, 'r') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        print line.strip()
        os.system('at -c ' + line[:2] + ' | grep task')
        print ('-' * 40) + "\n" + line

os.system("rm " + filename)
```

This is untested code, but it should work the same as your original code.

Comment: Do note that it will remove your `attemp.txt`, which I'm not sure if its truly intended to do so (I'd honestly keep the txt file just in case I had to re-run it)